# Google Documents List API version 3.0 - How to sort files by file name

Tags: google-drive-api

I had succesed to get file list with url

> https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/folder:root/contents?v=3

But the file list is in updated-time order.

How to order by file name.

In Google Documents List API version 2.0 , `[orderby=title]` can do it.

In version 3.0, this parameter does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Its `orderBy` not `orderby`. Refer to the answer at: [Google Drive Api not returning results by descending order of number of occurrences of word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529474/google-drive-api-not-returning-results-by-descending-order-of-number-of-occurren)