# Google drive API - List orderBy does not work

Tags: google-drive-api

To list files/folders in sorted order using query with 'orderBy' option.

Below 'orderBy' title does not to work. (Ref: [Google Drive Api not returning results by descending order of number of occurrences of word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529474/google-drive-api-not-returning-results-by-descending-order-of-number-of-occurren))

```
function list_google_drive_contents(id, parent) {
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
        function read_files(page_token, list) {             
            var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list(page_token);
            console.log(page_token);
            request.execute(function(resp) {                
                if(resp.items) {
                    list    = list.concat(resp.items);              
                }
                if(resp.nextPageToken) {
                    page_token.pageToken = resp.nextPageToken; 
                    read_files(page_token, list);
                } else {
                    handle_google_drive_file_list(list, parent);
                }               
            });
        }
        var query = "'" + id + "' in parents";
        read_files({'q' : query, 'orderBy' : 'title'}, []);
    });
}
```

What is wrong?

More info on 'orderBy':
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/v2/reference

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing two very different apis (fhe old documents list and the new drive api). 
The drive api doesnt support sorting but the old one does. Yes I hate that too.